# Do I <verb> ....?

Tags: tone

> Do I get all my packages?
>   Do I get any food for supper?
>   Do I have ....?

Does this kind of sentence pattern starting with "Do I " when said as expressions for querying information sound more like kind of interrogation or challenge, for native speakers?  It does for me sometimes, but then I don't know if my sense of the tones in oral English is accurate.

Comment: Yes, most of the time 'Do I get any tea?!', at least, is petulant and confrontational, meaning 'Why haven't you brought me my tea?!'. The same structure is, however, used for the unmarked ('straight') query, as here: _'You're on $35K a year.' _'Do I get expenses?'

Comment: Agreed. In my experience, petulance is marked by stress on the subject, plain query by stress on the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though it technically isn't rude, "do I" makes a phrase sound too blatant.  Usually there are politer forms of saying something.  "Do I" makes it sound like a command, because it somewhat implies that you will get what you asked for, instead of leaving room for uncertainty.  Therefore, it implies that the person is obligated to give you what you wanted.  For example, using "may I" implies that the person is not obligated to give it to you if they are affected by certain factors.

However, when you start a question with "do I have", it sometimes sounds like you are asking yourself a question.

Nevertheless, there's no solid rule for this, and sometimes you can get away from using "ruder language" by speaking with a polite tone.  Doing so wouldn't make you seem rude at all. :)